# Time Complexity of Finding All Possible Sums

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

Here is a solution to an algorithm that wants me to find all possible sums given an array of coins and their corresponding quantities. I am having a hard time deriving the time complexity of this algorithm. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!!

```
const coins = [1, 2, 3];
const quantity = [1, 2, 2];

const possibleSums = (coins, quantity) => {
  const uniqueSums = new Set([0]);

  for (let i = 0; i < coins.length; i++) {
    const currentSums = new Set();
    for (let j = 1; j <= quantity[i]; j++) {
      for (let sum of uniqueSums) {
        currentSums.add((coins[i] * j) + sum);
      }
    }
    for (let sum of currentSums) {
      uniqueSums.add(sum);
    }
  }

  return uniqueSums.size - 1;
}
```

Comment: Here's the "brute force" way to determine the time-complexity. Looks like every '.add' can be considered an operation. So, add a counter variable, increment it every time a '.add' is called, print it at the end of the function, and try to determine a pattern using coins and quantity.

Comment: What do you want the complexity to be in terms of? Usually people want a big-O value in terms of the *length* of a given array, but this algorithm varies based on the actual *values* in one of the arrays.

Comment: I believe it is O(n^3) where n is the length of the coins array. Outer and inner loop are O(n^2) and then there is one more loop inside the quantity for loop which makes it O(n^3).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the average complexity is O(n * m) where n is the total amount of coins available (i.e. the sum of coin[i] * quantity[i] for all i) and m is the number of unique sums possible (i.e. what you're trying to calculate).

The tricky part is that the size of uniqueSums doesn't grow in a predictable manner since it depends on the exact values used, so I can't see an obvious argument to prove it isn't actually something smaller in practice (e.g. O(n + m) or something like that)

Basically, best case is O(n) (if most of the size of uniqueSums comes from the very last iteration, so it never has to be iterated upon), worst case is O(n * m) (opposite case, if uniqueSums reaches its final size immediately), average case probably still O(n * m) but I'm not 100% sure.